# Can't transfer 4gbyte file from USB flash drive to Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, ntfs, xcode, flash-memory

I've been unable to transfer XCode 3.2.6, a 4gbyte .dmg file, from a USB flash drive to 2 snow leopard MacBooks.  It stops at 2.2gbytes with an error.  The flash drive is formatted with NTFS from a win7 machine.

How do I get XCode on Snow Leopard?  Should I do something special with the flash drive?

I understand 3.2.6 is the last XCode version to work on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version of Xcode that works for Snow Leopard is *Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 for Snow Leopard*. It's only 1.64 GB. To access it, log in to http://developer.apple.com/ios, look for "Other Xcode" button, click it and you should see the following

[image]

Comment: Excellent, I'll try that.  What about for Leopard?  Will that work for Leopard as well?

Comment: Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS 4.2 is the Xcode for Leopard. Your copy may be corrupted during download which explains the error you reported.

Comment: When I login to the developer downloads section of the Apple website, I just see "Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3 for Snow Leopard" and "Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2".  Seems that 3.2.5 is the latest for Leopard?

Comment: The latest 3.2.x I have in my backup is Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2 for Leopard (file system 3.78 GB). I gave you the benefit of the doubt when you stated 3.2.6 in your question. :)

Comment: I thought the latest was 3.2.6 for snow leopard and 3.2.5 for leopard.  The problem seems to be an issue with USB drives and macs though... I can't seem to transfer these big files fully.

Comment: What I normally do with USB thumb drives is use Disk Utility to format them as Mac OS X (Journaled), then copy whatever I needed to copy before reformatting the USB drives back to whatever it was before. Just make sure you back before formatting the USB drives.

Comment: I'll try that, I had ntfs because I need to frequently transfer files from the PC to mac and viceversa, but I'll just purchase another thumb drive...

Comment: If your Mac and PC are on the same network, ftp or WebDAV might be faster.

Comment: Where is Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard?  I'm in the develop downloads on Apple's site and I only see Xcode 4.3.3, 4.3.2, 4.3.1, 4.3, 4.2.1, 4.2 and 4.1 all saying "for Lion".  When I click on Xcode 4.2, the filename I download is "installxcode_42_lion.dmg".  Are you sure this works on Snow Leopard?